# Append UIImage to mail

Tags: swift, xcode, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I would like to send an e-mail from my app. I have solved the problem so far and the sending also works flawlessly:

```
func showMailComposer() {
    
    guard MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() else {
        return
    }
    
    let composer = MFMailComposeViewController()
    composer.mailComposeDelegate = self
    composer.setToRecipients(["email@gmail.com"])
    composer.setSubject("example")
    composer.setMessageBody(""

        
       , isHTML: false)
    
    present(composer, animated: true)
}
```

Now I would like to send a signature, that was made by the user, with the mail. I already exported the signature as UIImage.

Now I do not know how I can attach the UIImage to the mail.

How do you do that?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can add attachment data using this api -
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller/1616885-addattachmentdata

```
func addAttachmentData(_ attachment: Data, 
              mimeType: String, 
              fileName filename: String)
```

From the docs -

> attachment
>
> The data to attach. Typically, this is the contents of a file that you want to include. This parameter must not be nil.
>
> mimeType
>
> The MIME type of the specified data. (For example, the MIME type for a JPEG image is image/jpeg.) For a list of valid MIME types, see http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/. This parameter must not be nil.
>
> filename
>
> The preferred filename to associate with the data. This is the default name applied to the file when it is transferred to its destination. Any path separator (/) characters in the filename are converted to underscore (_) characters prior to transmission. This parameter must not be nil.

---

#### UPDATE

For the attached screenshot -
[image]

The call would look like -

```
composer.addAttachmentData(
    unterschriftFoto?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.99) ?? Data(),
    mimeType: "image/jpeg",
    filename: "unterschriftFoto.jpeg" /// or whatever you like to call it
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But I always get errors. . . What am I doing wrong? A picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbcPb.png

Comment: See the UPDATE.

Comment: Ok Thank you very much. . . I have one more question: And now I always get the mistakes:

Value of optional type ’UIImage?' must be unwrapped to refer to member ’jpegData' of wrapped base type ’UIImage'

and

Value of optional type ’Data?' must be unwrapped to a value of type ’Data'

How can i fix the error?

Probably a beginner’s mistake. . . I don’t have too much experience yet. . .

Comment: Thank you again! It now works flawlessly!!

Comment: Please consider marking an answer as accepted (in case it works) so it can help others.